# Why isn't the a-frame click event working?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I'm trying to figure out why my console isn't recording my log statements in my click event handlers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my JS Fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/tznezkqo/

I'm using A-Frame version 5.0

Here's my HTML

```
 <!-- Player -->
  <a-entity camera universal-controls="movementControls: checkpoint" checkpoint-controls="mode: animate"
            position="0 1.764 0">
    <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500" position="0 0 -1"
              geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03;" material="color: #CCC; shader: flat;">
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>


  <a-entity id="box" cursor-listener geometry="primitive: box" material="color: blue" position="-2 2.2 -1.5"></a-entity>
```

and my JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  AFRAME.registerComponent('cursor-listener', {
    init: function () {
      this.el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        console.log('I was clicked at: ', evt.detail.intersection.point);
      });
    }
  });

  AFRAME.registerComponent('collider-check', {
    dependencies: ['raycaster'],
    init: function () {
      this.el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersected', function () {
        console.log('Player hit something!');
      });
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you'll have to make sure the component is registered *before* the elements are used.

here's a modified version of your example: https://jsfiddle.net/pj3m4obt/2/

```
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('cursor-listener', {
    init: function () {
         this.el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        console.log('I was clicked at: ', evt.detail.intersection.point);
      });
    }
  });
</script>
<body>
...
<a-entity id="box" cursor-listener geometry="primitive: box" material="color: blue" position="-2 2.2 -1.5"></a-entity>
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks

I just moved my app.js to the head instead of at the bottom of my sheet. 

Really appreciate your help.